# How do I connect to Adsense Account?

Tags: google-search-console

I have to add a script section to the head section on the website.  I am modifying the html.html.twig file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "ca-pub-6243578269823283",
            enable_page_level_ads: true
        });
    </script>
    <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
    <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">--
  </head>
  <body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>
    <a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable skip-link">
      {{ 'Skip to main content'|t }}
    </a>
    {{ page_top }}
    {{ page }}
    {{ page_bottom }}
    <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </body>
</html>`
```

This seems to not work. Google responded and said I still have to connect my site to Adsense for verification. How do I do this? I have the Adsense module installed but I can't use it until I have an account. This script is for verification so that I can have an account with my website.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already look into dedicated modules for this? There is

[Google AdSense integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/adsense) and [Simple AdSense](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_adsense). The first one is more advanced, the second is simpler, but less flexible.

For both, you just have to copy over some values, and the module will take carte of the rest.

Comment: I'm sure both of those modules are for when you have a google Adsense account already set up. I need to paste the code below in the head tags of the document so I can connect my website to google adsense and get an account.

Comment: <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "ca-pub-6243578269823283",
            enable_page_level_ads: true
        });
    </script>

Comment: I added the script code to html.html.twig and it didn't work, google responded and said they can't connect.

Comment: Aren't there alternative methods like uploading a file, or configuring a DNS key?